# bash + monitor disk space usage and execute script if used space reached the threshold

Tags: linux, bash, awk, rhel, cron

We want to follow the used space of `/var/hadoop/hdfs` partition , by way if used space is more the `50%` then as results we run the script – `do_action.bash` , finally this command should be in crontab and should be run every 1 hour

Example of the partition hdfs

```
df -Ph | grep 'hdfs'
/dev/sdc                     20G  1.7G   18G   9% /var/hadoop/hdfs
```

What we did until now is the below syntax that print `"run the script do_action.bash"` , in case threshold is more then **50%** used ,

```
df -Ph | grep 'hdfs' | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 50) print "run the scriot do_action.bash"}'
```

but how to add the execution of the script - `do_action.bash`

we try

```
df -Ph | grep 'hdfs' | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 50) print "run the scriot do_action.bash"}' && bash /opt/do_action.bash
```

but above isn’t right because script `- /opt/do_action.bash` runs in any case

Comment: Would this help you ? https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/shell-script-to-watch-the-disk-space.html (put your script in place of the *mail* statement for example…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run `df /path/to/directory` to get the `df` output of that directory. For example, on my system:

```
$ df -Ph /home/terdon
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p6  669G  186G  450G  30% /home
```

So you don't need to `grep hdfs`, you can get it directly and then simply look at the second line (`NR==2` in awk) to skip the header. With that in mind, you can then set `awk`'s exit status using `exit()` and use that with the regular shell `&&` to execute your script. Something like this:

```
df -Ph /var/hadoop/hdfs | tr -d '%' | 
    awk 'NR==2{ exit $5>50 ? 0 : 1}' && /opt/do_action.bash
```

Or even shorter:

```
df -Ph /var/hadoop/hdfs | awk 'NR==2{exit ((0+$5) <= 50)}' && /opt/do_action.bash
```

`&&` means "only run the next command if the previous command was successful". The `exit $5>50 ? 0 : 1` will set the awk command's exit code to 0 (success) if `$5` is greater than `50`, so the script will only run if `$5>50`.

Here's the first awk script written in a more verbose, but easier to understand form:

```
awk '{ 
        if(NR==2){ 
            if($5>50){
              exitStatus=0
            }
            else{
               exitStatus=1
            }
            exit(exitStatus)
        }
    }'
```

Comment: is it possible to run additional script over pipe ? as  && /opt/do_action.bash && && /opt/do_action_1.bash && && /opt/do_action_2.bash

Comment: @yael yes, of course, there is no limit (there is a limit, but it's very high and is more about MAX_ARGS than the number of commands per se). You can do `command1 && command2 && command3 && command4 && command5 && command6` and each will only run if the previous one was successful.

Comment: To paraphrase Crocodile Dundee: That (`&&`) isn't  pipe, THIS (`|`) is a pipe.